# How to know if user is active in firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make chat app in Flutter with Firebase and had a trouble which I can't know if my user is active (using the app) or not.
I tried to make a native code that run when app terminated but didn't work.

I tried to make it with lifecycle method but didn't work .

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
     
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(id).update({"active" : false});
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
```

But it does nothing when app is terminated. Does anyone have an idea for it in Flutter?

Comment: Try to check `AppLifecycleState.paused` also.

Comment: Same result, no thing happens

Comment: I guess when app is terminated no thing run even in any state of AppLifeCycleState

Comment: Check if it runs with a `print`.  Try to remove `super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee that your `update({"active" : false})` code will still be able to execute the write operation when the user is no longer actively using the app. Firestore has no built-in capability to write something in the database *after* the client has disconnected.

Firebase's other database: the Realtime Database, does have the ability with its [`onDisconnect` handlers](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage#offline-capabilities), which are delayed write instructions that you to the database when you *are* connected, and which the database then executes once it detects that the connection is gone.

You can combine the Realtime Database with Firestore as shown this documentation page on [connecting Realtime Database and Firestore to get presence information into Firestore too](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence). I'd also recommend reading the non-Flutter specific documentation on [building a presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample) with the Realtime Database.

Comment: Ok, this worked very well when I terminate the app but when I close wifi it does nothing do you have an idea to know if user has connection or not and send it to firebase when close wifi or data

Comment: Give it a few minutes. When you close the app, the SDK typically can inform the server that it is disconnecting, and thus the server runs the `onDisconnect` handlers straight away. When you disconnect the wifi (and many other scenarios) you have a so-called dirty disconnect and the client can't inform the server straight away. In that case the server will detect that the client is gone after a few minutes when the socket times out, and will run the `onDisconnect` handlers at that point.